# Traversing with foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the following API response -

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "430916.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430916.jpg",
        "430917.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430917.jpg",
        "430918.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430918.jpg"
    },
    "error": ""
}
```

How would I get the image paths in AngularJS?
what would the parsing code be?

Comment: you mean in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"> {{ value }} </div>
```

Comment: so in controller it'll be like - <br> $scope.data = response; right?

Comment: ya, follow another ans.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular forEach if you want in controller.

```
 angular.forEach(obj.data,function(value,key){
     console.log(value)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var response = {
  "status": 200,
  "data": {
    "430916.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430916.jpg",
    "430917.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430917.jpg",
    "430918.jpg": "abc.com/dsbfi/8/430918.jpg"
  },
  "error": ""
}

var images = []; //this will contain all the uri's

for(i in response.data){
 images.push(response.data[i])
}
```